# What does this jquery + form construct do?

Tags: jquery

I am dealing with jQuery code as follows:

```js
function formSubmit() {
    $('#myform').attr('action', "./myFilter.action");
    $('#myform').submit();
}
```

The form:

```jsp
<form name="myform" action="myAction"   id="myform">
</form>
```

Noticing that `myFilter.action` is called before `myAction`. But I don't understand how or why that is happening. Can someone explain?

Comment: it looks like the `formSubmit()` is triggered (somewhere) and it creates an action and submits, since it does not prevent the default behaviour, it may also submit to the original action

Comment: Please elaborate on the usage of `<s:form>`. Is `s:` an alias for the HTML namespace, or otherwise rendered in a way that produces HTML (such as via ASP.NET)?

Comment: @zzzzBov It is Struts2 form tag. But it is unrelated in this context, because it will produce simple html form.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming `<s:form>` is being treated as an HTML `<form>` element by the browser:***

The jQuery code uses [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) to change the `[action]` attribute of the form.

The [`[action]`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#attr-fs-action) attribute tells the form what URL to send the data to via either a GET or POST request, depending on what the `[method]` attribute is set to.

The [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit) method is then used to force the form to submit the data it contains to the URL previously specified.

---

<sub>* This is a sizable assumption, as the `s:` namespace may be aliased to pretty much anything, so it's unclear as to how the element is meant to be used without additional context.</sub>

Comment: The action attribute is *not* the html form attribute.

Comment: @RomanC, I'm not sure I understand what that comment is with regard to.

Comment: *The [action] attribute tells the form what URL*, this is wrong. The action attribute doesn't have URL. This *is* just because it's *not* html form.

Comment: What do you don't understand? But if your edit the question and remove the prefix used for the tag, then you were ok.

Comment: @RomanC, ah yes, I hadn't noted the `s:` namespace prefix. I suppose it's possible that the `<s:form>` element wasn't being used or otherwise treated as an HTML form. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It's not html element, it's JSP tag.

Comment: It's suspicious but looks like struts2 form.

Answer (score -1):

You can use that code if you handle `onclick` event of the button, that doesn't have submit event.

```
<button onclick="formSubmit()">Submit</button>
```